# How to stop a snap package downloading

Tags: snap

When I start installing a snap package, and cancel after that, I get back to the command prompt, but when I see the process that are consuming the bandwidth, I can see that snapd is still downloading the snap. I tried the command `snap abort id_of_operation` but it doesn't give anything, the command `snap changes` shows that the operation has been aborted, but snapd is still downloading.

So, is there a way to stop the downloading ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not right now, though once the download has completed, snapd will abort the operation as requested.

Note that the client is supposed to abort the operation when you ctrl+c it-- this is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1596077).

**Update:** This bug was fixed in snapd v2.20.1.

Comment: does it have any drawbacks, if you stop a snap install in-the-middle?

Comment: There should be no side effects other than not installing the snap in question.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug, but you can zircumvent it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> (pause in background) and then kill the process with:

```
kill -kill $(pgrep snap -la|grep -v /usr/lib/snapd/snapd|cut -d\  -f1)
```

Answer (score 3):

best way is to run:

`snap changes`

then:

`snap abort id`

**id** will be provided when you run `snap changes`